# Отрабатывает debugger до axios, после чего считывается axios и не заходит внутрь

Tags: reactjs, axios

Отрабатывает debugger до axios, после чего считывается axios и не заходит внутрь, не в get, не в then
Переустановка axios, другой запрос, размещение его в другом месте не работают.
В чем может быть проблема?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте разрыв строки делать не в вызове метода, а в его аргементах. Иногда такая запись может путать интерпретатор.

```
 axios.get(
   'http...'
 ).then(response => {
    ...
 }).catch(e => debugger);
```

Ну и блок `.catch` не помешает, чтоб наверняка

Comment: Спасибо за совет,но к сожалению результат все тот же, внутрь axios просто не заходит.

Comment: Я затрудняюсь ответить почему вам это не помогло. Вот пример https://jsfiddle.net/0rjy4atc/ где делается то же самое и запрос падает в `catch` потому что на сервере нет заголовока `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` и соответственно не получится туда AJAX делать.